# Creating buttons with JS that keeps variable upon creation

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, onclick

I'm creating a HTML table by using JavaScript.

I want add button to the cell with index 5 on each row.

The `console.log(i)` before the `btn.onclick`... writes the value of `i` but when the different buttons are pressed all the outputs are the same and are always 10.

I guess this is because the variable in the function gets updated.

How do you make it so that the button on each row outputs the value of i when the button is "created"

Take a look at my code

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById("my_table").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var newRow = tableRef.
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(5);

  btn = document.createElement('input');
  btn.type = "button";
  btn.className = "btn";
  btn.value = "My button";

  console.log(i);

  btn.onclick = function() {
    console.log(i);
  };

  newCell.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets follow the JavaScript execution step by step.

1. You get access to the table
2. You create the loop which iterates from 0 to 9 (10 steps)
3. On each step you create the button and assign listener function to the onclick event.
4. The listener function keep reference to the `i` variable.
5. When you loop reach the end
6. All your elements have rendered to the screen and buttons are available
7. At this moment `i` variable is equal to `9`.
8. You click a button.
9. After clicking the button your function go to the `i` variable and fetch the value.
10. The `i` value is equal to 9 and therefore it prints 9.

To fix this you can move `var i;` to the loop statement and replace var with let.

See example below

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById("my_table").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Use let here
  var newRow = tableRef.
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(5);

  btn = document.createElement('input');
  btn.type = "button";
  btn.className = "btn";
  btn.value = "My button";

  console.log(i);

  btn.onclick = function() {
    console.log(i);
  };

  newCell.appendChild(btn);
}
```

For more information you can read the [article](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/)

I hope this helps you